# why is my htaccess doing the proper url but loads 401 error page?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been researching for days trying to figure out what is wrong with my htaccess and no luck. In both cases I get the url acting correctly but it loads a 401 error page

Right now, I have `localhost/test/profile.php?username=gadgetster`

I want it to show `localhost/test/profile/gadgetster` in the url

And for `localhost/test/pages/aboutus.php`

I want to show `localhost/test/aboutus.php`

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#username
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ test/profile.php?username=$1


#pages folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pages/
RewriteRule pages/(.*)$ test/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

EDIT:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#------------------remove index || index.php---------------------------------
# remove /index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# remove /index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]


#------------------remove pages/ dirctory---------------------------------
# externally redirect /dir/foo to /foo
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ test/$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ test/pages/$1 [L]


#-------------------remove .php-----------------------------------------
#  externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ test/$1.php [L]


#-------------------User Profile-----------------------------------------
# Remove long profile url to simple 'profile/username'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ test/profile/$1/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/$ test/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]


#Deny access to htaccess
<files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Place your .htaccess in your `/test/` directory**

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

#pages folder
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/ [NC]
RewriteRule pages/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#username
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/pages/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)/?$ pages/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/pages/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I do have the .htaccess in 'test' already. You code didn't change anything, I still get the page not found error even though it does do what I want for the url. How does it matter if I put RewriteBase /test/ or write test/ everywhere like I did?

Comment: If you have `/test/.htaccess` then make sure to keep these suggested rules on top of your .htaccess. Also edit your question and show your existing rules in `/test/.htaccess` so that I can investigate and suggest you better.

Comment: I added my whole htaccess, didn't think it mattered if I removed unnecessary things for the question but I edited the code above.

Comment: check updated answer for your full .htaccess, use it as is in your `/test/.htaccess`

Comment: I replaced my whole htaccess with your code and I still get the 401 error page. The .htaccess is inside the 'test' folder. Ah this is frustrating :/

Comment: Change your `Options` line to: `Options +Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks`

Comment: I get the right url but the page "Object not found!"

Comment: What URL do you see in browser when you get `Object not found`?

Comment: Have made an update that will redirect `localhost/test/about.php` to `localhost/test/about`

Comment: ok thanks for your help but you are not answering my question.. I didn't ask for that

Comment: I fixed that issue, and it had nothing to do with the .php right now the page opens but it is missing stuff for some reason Warning: require_once(conn.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory in... even though there is a directory

Comment: do I need to have .htaccess file in both test and pages directories?

Comment: No you don't need `/test/pages/.htacces`. Added another rule for handling `localhost/test/aboutus` OR `localhost/test/aboutus.php`

Comment: Last comment before I signoff (it is damn late here) There is already a rule to rewrite `/test/profile/gadgetster` to `/test/profile.php?gadgetster?username=gadgetster`

Comment: You should start making some effort to resolve it after seeing these endless number of updates to resolve other problems.

Comment: I have been sitting trying to figure it out for a week now. I am not just waiting for an answer, I am trying to figure it out but nothing I do works. I have limited knowledge in htaccess

Comment: thank you for all your help! much appreciated! you spent a lot of your time helping me out

Comment: Yes I did but I'm felling relieved that things worked out for you eventually.

Comment: Any htaccess questions I have, I'm looking for you!

Comment: I try my level best to answer but sometimes it takes a bit more time to understand OP's local setup and config.